# Problema con macros excel

Tags: excel, vba, macros

una consulta  Como puedo hacer para que en el boton aparte de traerme los datos de la tabla en la hoja BD , me pueda traer las imagenes?

```
introducir el código aquí
 Sub Buscador()
    Dim valor_Buscado As Integer

    Dim celda As String
    Dim celda1 As String
    Dim celda2 As String
    Dim celda3 As String
    Dim celda4 As String


    valor_Buscado = Range("a3").Value

    celda = Application.VLookup(valor_Buscado, Sheets("BD").Range("B2:G16"), 2, 0)
    Range("B3") = celda

    celda1 = Application.VLookup(valor_Buscado, Sheets("BD").Range("B2:G16"), 3, 0)
    Range("B4") = celda1

    celda2 = Application.VLookup(valor_Buscado, Sheets("BD").Range("B2:G16"), 4, 0)
    Range("B5") = celda2

    celda3 = Application.VLookup(valor_Buscado, Sheets("BD").Range("B2:G16"), 2, 0)
    Range("B6") = celda3

   celda4 = Application.VLookup(valor_Buscado, Sheets("BD").Range("B2:G16"), 6, 0)
   Range("B7") = celda4

  End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero que aparesca en esta hoja y estos campos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero como pueden ver no me sale correctamente

Answer (score 4):

Por lo que entiendo, la búsquedas te las realiza de forma correcta, y es la hora de pegar el valor de las variables en las celdas

Y utilizas para pegar los valores de esas variables, siempre la misma columna B, por lo que los valores te los va pegando en B3, B4, B5,B6
Para que te las vaya colocando en las diferentes columnas, deberias de cambiar el valor de las mismas: B3, C3, D,3, E3

```
celda = Application.VLookup(valor_Buscado, Sheets("BD").Range("B2:G16"), 2, 0)
'Te pega en contenido de la variable celda en B3
Range("B3") = celda

celda1 = Application.VLookup(valor_Buscado, Sheets("BD").Range("B2:G16"), 3, 0)
'Te pega el contenido de la variable celda1 en B4, no debería de ser C3 ?
Range("C3") = celda1
```

Para guardar imágenes te pongo una función:

```
Function inserta_foto()
    'seleccionamos la imagen a insertar y le damos un nombre
    SavePicture RutaTotal.Picture, "logo.jpg"
    'Selecciona la hoja1, y la imagen por el nombre almacenado anteriormente "logo.jpg"
    Worksheets(hoja1).Pictures.Insert("logo.jpg").Select
        'Aqui la formateamos para adaptarla al rango elegido
        Whit Selection.ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .Top = Range("B48:C50").Top + 1
            .Left = Range("B48:C50").Left + 2
            .Width = Range("B48:C50").Whidt - 5
            .Height = Range("B48:C50").Heoght - 5
        End With
    End Function
```

EDITADO:

Para buscar imágenes en nuestro disco:

```
'La variable RutaExcel guarda ruta donde está el archivo excel
RutaExcel = ThisWorkbook.Path
'La ruta total desde el patch del archivo
RutaTotal = RutaActual & "\Departamentos\" & "Contabilidad.jpg"
```

Comment: Si, ya habia solucionado ese problema de los datos , en cuanto a insertar la imagen , como lo haría si las imágenes están en una carpeta? Y quisiera que al seleccionar una  un departamento , me salga esa foto , tengo varias imagenes para cada departamento

Comment: Edité el código, primero seleccionas la imagen desde RutaTotal, luego la almacenas con SavePicture en "logo.jpg" y luego la insertas en el control de imagen que hayas puesto en tu excel